# Chmod recursively directories only?

Tags: python

It's not work fo me:

```
target_dir = "a/b/c/d/e/"
os.makedirs(target_dir,0777)
```

os.chmod work only for last directory ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `os.walk` to traverse directories. (Below not tested, experiment it yourself)

```
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    os.chmod(r, 0o777)
```

Comment: Good one! I can confirm that it works for me.  The trick is that `topdown` defaults to `True`.  I was worried that it would try to walk a directory it doesn't have permission for.

Comment: Actually I was wrong - I wasn't testing it properly: it chmods the parent of the directory that it should be chmoding.  My answer below really does work for me.

Answer (score 1):

ghostdog74's answer almost works, but it tries to walk into the directory before it chmods it.  So the real answer is less elegant:

```
os.chmod(path , 0o777)
for root,dirs,_ in os.walk(path):
    for d in dirs :
        os.chmod(os.path.join(root,d) , 0o777)
```

Comment: I would explicitly chmod them inside the inner loop.   Your files normally need different permissions from the directories, so it make sense to do them in two separate lines of code.

Answer (score -1):

One line version for this is:

```
list(map(lambda x: os.chmod(x[0], 0o775), os.walk(target_dir)))
```

It is helpful when you have to use python console to make these changes, probably better to use the more readable `for` loop version suggested above in production code.

Comment: Just use a list comprehension, `[os.chmod(root, 0o755) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(target_dir)]`.